# Is there a way way to generate a custom error message using narginchk in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab is removing narchk function in future releases and I am trying to change some code to use narginck instead. Now with nargchk, the output was a string and I could pass it to an if statement to display my own error message. Something like

```
if ~isempty(nargchk(min, max, nargin))
  error('custom error message')
end
```

narginchk automatically gives an error not a string, so I was wondering if there is a way to give a custom error message with narginchk

Comment: Why use `nargchk`? Just use `nargin` and check yourself.

Comment: There are actually more conditions in the if statement which I didn't write, so it just looks ugly. That is what I will do though, if narginchk doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot supply a custom error message to `nargchk` and related functions.

There is no need to use `nargchk` in your case since you don't need default values or anything, just simply check the value of `nargin`.

```
if nargin > max || nargin < min
    error('custom error message');
end
```

Alternately, you could use `assert` to eliminate the `if` statement.

```
assert(nargin <= max && nargin >= min, 'Custom Error Message');
```

If you really want to use one of those functions, you could wrap it inside of a `try`/`catch` statement and provide a custom error message

```
try
    narginchk(min, max, nargin)
catch ME
    throw(MException(ME.identifier, 'my custom message'))
end
```

Comment: I can of course do that, except that there are actually a few more conditions on the if statement which I didn't write up there. So the code ends up looking kinda ugly.  If there is no workaround with narginchk, that I what I might end up doing though

Comment: @SharanBanagiri You could always make your validation a subfunction to encapsulate that functionality somewhere and clean things up. But no, there is no way to specify a custom error to `narginchk`

Comment: @SharanBanagiri I have added an alternative approach using `try`/`catch`